Not able to anchor references in a custom bibliography environment
I am trying to have a file with two bibliographies, each of them with a different kind of labeling (one should show the labeling [1], [2],..., whilst the other one has a custom labeling [A-1], [A-2],...). To this end, I have added a new environment which creates a customized bibliography (see the environment "theprefixbibliography" in the MWE below).
The problem is that it seems that there is no anchoring at all in the items of the customized environment. More precisely, when I click on the link of any of the "usual" reference labels [1], [2],..., it sends me to the appropriate bibliography item, whereas if I click on the link of the customized labels [A-1], [A-2],..., it sends me to the beginning of the document. Here's some warnings I get concerning the customized bibliography:
name{cite.R-A1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
name{cite.R-A2} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one

Question:
How can I solve this issue? I have found this way of creating the custom bibliography around here but I am not able to find it again to see if there is any workaround.
This is the MWE I am using for generating this example. I have added a blank page at the beginning just to show how the custom reference labels jump to this first page. The MWE also has two files containing references.
MWE.tex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{theprefixbibliography}[2]
{
    \begin{thebibliography}{#2}
        \def\@biblabel##1{[#1-##1]}%
        \def\@bibitem##1{\item\if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout
            {\string\bibcite{##1}{#1-\the\value{\@listctr}}}\fi\ignorespaces}
    }
    {\end{thebibliography}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This page intentionally left blank.

\newpage

\cite{R-1}

\cite{R-A1}

\cite{R-2}

\cite{R-A2}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
    \input{Ref.bib}
\end{thebibliography}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography 2}
\begin{theprefixbibliography}{A}{A-1}
    \input{Ref2.bib}
\end{theprefixbibliography}

\end{document}

Ref.bib
\bibitem{R-1}
Reference 1

\bibitem{R-2}
Reference 2

Ref2.bib
\bibitem{R-A1} 
Reference A1

\bibitem{R-A2}
Reference A2


\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{theprefixbibliography}[2]
{
    \begin{thebibliography}{#2}
        \def\@biblabel##1{[#1-##1]}%
        \def\@bibitem##1{%
        \@skiphyperreftrue\H@item\@skiphyperreffalse
         \Hy@raisedlink{%
          \hyper@anchorstart{cite.##1}\relax\hyper@anchorend
        }%
        \if@filesw
         \begingroup
           \let\protect\noexpand
           \immediate\write\@auxout{%
             \string\bibcite{##1}{#1-\the\value{\@listctr}}%
           }%
         \endgroup
       \fi}}
    {\end{thebibliography}}
      
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This page intentionally left blank.

\newpage

\cite{R-1}

\cite{R-A1}

\cite{R-2}

\cite{R-A2}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
 \bibitem{R-1}
Reference 1

\bibitem{R-2}
Reference 2
\end{thebibliography}

\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliography 2}
\begin{theprefixbibliography}{A}{A-1}
\bibitem{R-A1} 
Reference A1

\bibitem{R-A2}
Reference A2
\end{theprefixbibliography}

\end{document}


Thanks a lot! This worked wonders.
